# How to convert a lambda function into a regular function?

Tags: python

```
a_min = [
    min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(',')),
        key=lambda i: int(str.strip(i).split('-')[-1])) for x in lst
]
```

I am trying to change the lambda into a regular function is there any way to do this?

Comment: *of course*. `lambda args: <some expression>` -> `def myfunction(args): return <some expression>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a normal method with one argument, that return a value:

```
def min_key_method(i):
    return int(str.strip(i).split('-')[-1])
```

Usage:

```
a_min = [
    min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(',')), key=min_key_method) for x in lst
]
```